# Add pagination numbers to wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination

Like i comment in title, i wish add pagination buttons to this loop. 1 2 3 next

```
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not really clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbered pagination by following this article, I use it on my own website and it works :

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Please avoid providing answer in an external source (e.g. link to another website). If it's deleted or the content is changed, the answer won't be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding pagination is very simple and just requires including the code into your page.

```
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can read more about pagination here: [Pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Comment: There are lots of examples that do what this code does but this is not what the OP is asking